# The DataOutputStream text from Server to Client is indented weird and produces a 4

Tags: java, server, stream, client, telnet

Right now, I'm trying to make a server that can display messages to the client when they connect (through localhost). When I connect through telnet, it gives me weird indentation. The code for the server is:

```
    private ServerSocket middleman;
    private int port = 8080;
    private Socket client;


protected void createSocketServer()
{

    try
    {
        while (true){
            middleman = new ServerSocket(port);
            client = middleman.accept();
            middleman.close();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line;

            //Client stuff
            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

            while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("echo: " + line);

                dOut.writeByte(1);
                dOut.writeUTF("Good day to you user. Here is a selection of poems " + "\n");
                dOut.writeUTF("1. Cupcake Poem"  + "\n");
                dOut.flush();

                //Response
                if(line.equals("cupcake")){
                    try{
                        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(poem);
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                        String poemLine;
                    while((poemLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuffer.append(poemLine);
                        stringBuffer.append("\n");
                    }
                    fileReader.close();
                    System.out.println("Contents of file:");
                    //System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
                    dOut.writeUTF(stringBuffer.toString());
                    dOut.flush();
            } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("wrong!, the line is:" + line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

On the client side, I'll open the command prompt and type `telnet localhost 8080` then I'll type something like "fish". It will print

```
[?]Good day to you user. here is a selection of poems
                                                       1. Cupcake Poem
```

Why does it do this? If I type "cupcake" on client, it will read the file, but have weird spacing. Is this something to do with Telnet?

Comment: looks like a missing ‚carriage return‘ control character. try changing ‚/n‘ into ‚/n/r‘. does that make a difference?

Comment: What is the purpose of `dOut.writeByte(1);`?

Comment: @MarioKohler Yes that does make a difference and makes it in line. However, at the beginning, it'll still put some sort of character

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I followed another example that used that. If I comment it out, it will print some random number in front...

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you do things in a very weird order. You get the input from the connection *before* you print the menu. It would make more sense if you first printed the menu, and *then* fetched the input, or the connected user would not know what to enter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I understand. I'm just trying to solve the stream issue first, before I touch it up

Answer (score 1):

For telnet the correct end-of-line sequence is `"\r\n"`. Newline by itself will only go down to the next line, but it will not back up to the first column, which what the carriage-return does.

Also note that the order matters, the telnet specifications says that it has to be `"\r\n"`, in that order.

Also, you don't have to append the output with the newline-sequence like you do. You can write it all as a single string:

```
dOut.writeUTF("1. Cupcake Poem\r\n");
```